# Obtaining a list of values from a dataframe with loc

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has the following form:

```
               miRNA miRTarBase ID 
1      hsa-let-7a-3p    MIRT038998 
2      hsa-let-7a-5p    MIRT000415 
3      hsa-let-7b-3p    MIRT038996 
4      hsa-let-7b-5p    MIRT001229 
6      hsa-let-7c-5p    MIRT000408
```

and when I save this dataframe to a csv file the information is like the following:

[image]

and the list that contains the indexes of the values that I want to extract is the following:

listT=[14, 35, 39, 79, 120,...]

As you can see, it manages to extract the values of 14 and 39 (marked in yellow), but it throws an error with the value of 35 because this does not exist in the dataframe. I believe that the error is that it is considering the values in column A and not the values of the indexes that appear in gray which are 1,2,3,...

The code that I made and throw me the error is the following:

```
for item in listT:
        print (df.loc[item,'miRNA'])

  File "d:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3082, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: 35
```

It might seem a silly question, but how I can do to print the items or put in a list of the values of the miRNAs that are in rows or positions in gray according to the Excel like 14, 35, 39, and so on.

**PD** For clarification purposes, if my list has the following values:

```
listT=[5,9,12]
```

I want to return this values of the CSV file (or dataframe) created:

[image]

Comment: "throw me the error": Please post the details about the error.

Comment: What is the variable "listT" that you're iterating over?

Comment: The dataframe you posted seems to have a non-consecutive index, too. It goes 1, 2, 3, 4, 6... Is that a typo or is that real?

Comment: [Pandas .iloc is the Purely integer-location based indexing for selection by position](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or you could use `df[df.index.isin(listT)]`

Answer (score 1):

When you save to csv, by default pandas turns the index of your dataframe into its own column (the first column). From the looks of it, then, your index has "holes".

So if you actually want the item whose index is 35, you're out of luck and it's not in the dataframe.

If you want the "35th item" regardless of what the index is, you'd use `df.iloc[34]` (note the off-by-1 here, as indices that are purely position-based start with 0).

Comment: thanks, but I want to retrieve the values that appear in positions 14, 35, 39 and so on. The values that appear on column A should not be considered.

Comment: That's what I explain in the last paragraph of my answer: Use `iloc` instead of `loc` in that case. And make sure to use the correct index. Position 14 gives you the 15th element, because position 0 gives you the first element